# Returning input in a loop

Tags: python

So I have been trying to return all inputs in a loop but for some reason, this is not working and it only returns the last input.

Would be glad to see you assisting me.

```
def boogiewoogie(lineinfile,speechpart):
    y = lineinfile.count(speechpart)
    for i in range(y):
        askuser = input('Enter '+speechpart+': ')
    return askuser
```

Actual result :-

```
> boogiewoogie('The NOUN VERB past the ADJECTIVE NOUN.','NOUN')

> Enter NOUN:  dog
> Enter NOUN:  duck
> 'duck'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing over `askuser` each round of the loop. Try storing all values in a list:

```
def boogiewoogie(lineinfile,speechpart):
    y = lineinfile.count(speechpart)
    askuser = []
    for i in range(y):
        askuser.append(input('Enter '+speechpart+': '))
    return askuser
```

Comment: Beat me to it, remember that looping is just performing that action for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning just the last one so all works fine. You should have i.e. list, append you data to the list and then return that list, something like:

```
def boogiewoogie(lineinfile, speechpart):
    y = lineinfile.count(speechpart)
    history = []
    for i in range(y):
        history.append(input('Enter '+speechpart+': '))
    return history
```

would produce expected:

```
Enter NOUN: dog
Enter NOUN: food
['dog', 'food']
```

I would also drop concatenation in favor of `format()` for readability reasons:

```
     history.append(input('Enter {}: '.format(speechpart)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no array or way to store the value, the previous value is dropped. Create an empty array then append it in the for loop.

```
List = []
for i in range(y):
       askuser = input('Enter '+speechpart+': ')
       List.append(askusr)
print List
```